# What does "current slow" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "current slow" in the following passage?

> The same thing happens to this day, though on a smaller scale,
>   wherever a sediment-laden river or stream emerges from a mountain
>   valley onto relatively flat land, dropping its load as the ***current
>   slows***: the water usually spreads out fanwise, depositing the sediment
>   in the form of a smooth, fan-shaped slope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this sentence 'current' is the noun (meaning a current of water) and "slows" is the verb, meaning to become slower. So the full meaning is:

> ...as the current of water becomes slower...